# How to add a second database value into an xml attribute using php

Tags: php, xml

I have a php file that creates a xml for a data feed. I would like to add a second value from my database to the title attribute, how ever when it try it the following way it just skips the title attribute al together. Is there any way to do this?

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>  
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">  
<channel>  
<title>Piano and keyboard shop RSS feed</title>
<description>Data feed for the website</description> 
<link>http://www.pianoandkeyboardshoponline.co.uk</link>';

mysql_select_db($database_dBconn, $dBconn);
$query_products = "SELECT id, Category, Manufacturer, Model, Color, Product, GTIN, MPN, BriefDescription, LargeImage1, Stock, price, Delivery_price FROM products";
$products = mysql_query($query_products, $dBconn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_products = mysql_fetch_assoc($products);
$totalRows_products = mysql_num_rows($products);

 while ($row_products = mysql_fetch_assoc($products)){
            echo'
        <item>
            <g:id>'.$row_products[id].'</g:id>
            <title>'.$row_products[Manufacturer].''.$row_products[Model].'</title>
            more attributes 
        </item>'; 
 }
echo '</channel> 
</rss>';
```

Any help suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide us with your database schema/table description? Column names etc.
Secondly, I'd suggest for you to use PDO class instead of mysql_* methods.

Comment: I have a table within my database called products in there I've got a fields in which some are called Category, Manufacturer etc. I just pull the values from the database.  I hope that is what you've meant. I have never worked with PDO class and not sure how to use it.